# How should I decode HTTP headers from bytes to string?

Tags: python, http, header

Basically I'm trying to make a small web server in python from scratch(just to learn) and I'm having issues with decoding the headers. The code boils down to this (I've simplified it to only the code related to the issue):

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('', 80))
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()

    print(addr[0])
    request = conn.recv(2048).decode('utf-8')

    headers = (
        'HTTP/1.0 200 OK',
        'Content-Type: text/html'
    )

    content = 'success'

    response = "\n".join(headers) + "\r\n\r\n" + content

    conn.sendall(bytes(response, 'UTF-8'))

    conn.close()
```

I installed the addon HttpRequester for Firefox to fiddle around with what I have currently and tried attaching a file, which led to the following error:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 386: invalid start byte`

How do I go about fixing this? Should I wrap the thing in try: and ignore requests which lead to exceptions of that kind?

Comment: So what bytes are in those headers?

Comment: It's probably that the file you attached isn't UTF8 encoded, and you're assuming that everything you're being sent is text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.4) has this to say about field parsing:

> Historically, HTTP has allowed field content with text in the ISO-8859-1 charset [ISO-8859-1], supporting other charsets only through use of [RFC2047] encoding.  In practice, most HTTP header field values use only a subset of the US-ASCII charset [USASCII]. Newly defined header fields SHOULD limit their field values to US-ASCII octets.  A recipient SHOULD treat other octets in field content (obs-text) as opaque data.

where [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) gives you an extension mechanism to use other character sets; these would be encoded to ASCII anyway and require an additional step to decode. Personally, I've never seen such headers actually being used in HTTP communication.

You can thus safely assume all headers can be decoded as Latin-1, and RFC 2047 headers can be dealt with separately later:

```
request = conn.recv(2048)
headers, sep, body = request.partition(b'\r\n\r\n')
headers = headers.decode('latin1')
```

This does assume that all headers fit in those 2048 bytes.

Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) decodes bytes directly, one on one, to Unicode code points; even for those fields that should be treated as *opaque data* can be decoded this way, even though that is probably the wrong codec for those headers. In practice, you probably won't come across such headers and even if you did, you'd not care about those anyway. The headers that matter are all  ASCII encoded.

Comment: a) RFC 2616 is obsolete. What's relevant here is RFC 7230 (which get's rid of encding defaults and RFC 2047 stuff).

b) Yes, you can always decode using ISO-8859-1, because it's a one-to-one mapping between bytes and characters. However, the result might not be what the sender intended.

Comment: @JulianReschke: thanks for the poke, I didn't do my homework right there. Updated for RFC 7230.